# "Operation not permitted" error when creating BitNami Django project

Tags: python, django, macos, file-permissions, bitnami

I'm trying to create a project using the BitNami Django stack. I am new to Django, BitNami, Python, and Mac terminal. When I attempt the following command:

```
bash-3.2$ django-admin.py startproject MySite
```

I receive the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I changed the permissions of the current working folder (my PyCharm projects folder) to be read/write for everyone, but still no luck.

How can I resolve this error and create my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was attempting to create my project in the wrong folder.

If you're using the BitNami Mac App Store version, as I was, projects must be created in the following location:

```
~/shared/django/django_projects
```

More details about creating projects using the App Store version of the BitNami Django stack can be found [here](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Mac_Store_Apps/BitNami_Django#Django_Specific_Usage). If you're not using the App Store version, or are running the Windows or Linux version, you can find more details on creating your project [here](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Django).

(And, for reference' sake, the thread wherein my problem was resolved can be found [here](http://community.bitnami.com/t/operation-not-permitted-error-when-creating-bitnami-django-project/20552/6).)